# Sort multidimensional array and keep index C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Is it possible to sort a multidimensional array (row by row) using sort in C++ such that I can keep the index?

For example,

```
13, 14, 5, 16
0, 4, 3, 2
7, 3, 7, 6
9, 1, 11, 12
```

Becomes:

```
{ 5,13,14,16}
{ 0,2,3,4 }
{ 3,6,7,7}
{ 1,9,11,12 }
```

And the array with the index would be:

```
{2,0,1,3}
{0,3,2,1}
{1,3,0,2}
{ 1,0,2,3}
```

Comment: Are you really looking for a "yes" or "no" answer?

Comment: @RSahu, we can say OP, _yes_ then lets go to hibernate ^_^

Answer (score 2):

First create the array of integer indices; here it is for 1D array:

```
int ind[arr.size()];
for( int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i)
    ind[i] = i;
```

Then create the comparison object. Here is a ballpark of that in C++99 lingo; for C++11 you can shortcut that by using a lambda:

```
struct compare
{
    bool operator()( int left, int right ) {
        return arr[left] < arr[right];
    }
};
```

The sort the index array using that functor:

```
std::sort( ind, ind+sizeof(arr), compare );
```

Finally, use the sorted index array to order the values array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. To sort row by row, you have to set the appropriate starting and ending point in the `sort` function.To keep the index part, you can first create pairs of the array elements and index using the `make_pair` command. After executing the above code, you can reconstruct the index array.

You will need to do something like this (I haven't tried it out though):

```
for (i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
{
  sort(matrix[i].begin(), matrix[i].end());
}
```

Remember to add the index as the second element in the pair, because the default comparision operator for pairs checks the first element, followed by the second element.

Comment: Sorting that way works, but i dont have idea how to do the index part

Comment: @Eli: I have explained the index part also. Look at the `make_pair` command. So when you sort, the numbers will also have information about the index as they will be a pair. After that, using the `.first` and `.second` command, you can extract the values and indices.